# Identifying & removing outliers from PCA & QQ plots

Tags: r, pca, outliers, quantile

I have a 132 x 107 dataset which consists of 2 patient types - (33 of patient 1) and (99 of patient 2).

I'm looking for outliers so I've run pca on the dataset and done qqplots of the 1st 4 components, using the following commands

```
pca = prcomp(data, scale. = TRUE)
plot(pca$x, pch = 20, col = c(rep("red", 33), rep("blue", 99)))
```

When I do the qqplot of the 2nd component using:

```
qqPlot(pca$x[,2],pch = 20, col = c(rep("red", 33), rep("blue", 99)))
```

the following graph shows 2 clear outliers - the red dots in the bottom left corner which are patient 1s.

[image: QQ Plot]

Is there any straightforward way of working out the index of these points in the data so they can be removed?

Comment: You are much more likely to receive a helpful answer if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) together with the code you have tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, I don't believe that the identify method is supported
in the `car` package (the source of `qqPlot()`)

Let's take a look at a PCA of the USArrests data...

```
pca <- prcomp(USArrests)
```

The plot of this using `qqPlot` is easy enough.

```
require(car)
qqPlot(pca$x[,2],pch = 20, col = c(rep("red", 33), rep("blue", 99)))
```

However, `qqPlot()` does not allow for point selection via `identify()`.

```
identify(qqPlot(pca$x[,2],pch = 20, col = c(rep("red", 33), rep("blue", 99))))
# numeric(0)
```

You can, however, make use of `qqnorm()` in the `stats` package.

```
identify(qqnorm(pca$x[,2],pch = 20, col = c(rep("red", 33), rep("blue", 99))))
```

This will produce a less sophisticated graph, but you should be able to add a line and confidence intervals manually via `qqline()` (also in `stats`) and a little more math.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the [identify](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/identify.html) method in R. Typically, run

```
identify(qqPlot(pca$x[,2],pch = 20, col = c(rep("red", 33), rep("blue", 99))))
```

and left-click on the points which you want to identify. The index of the points in the score vector should be the same as in the original data.

Answer (score 2):

You can also visualize influence using the `fviz_pca_ind()` function in the `factoextra` library, as follows:

```
require(factoextra)
pca = prcomp(mydata)
fviz_pca_ind(pca,
         col.ind = "contrib", # Color by contribution
         gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07") #assign gradient
         )
```

This automatically labels the individuals, and colours them by their influence.